# Maximum size of Hard cache of an ImageDownloader

Tags: android, caching, dalvik

My question is that.. in this [ImageDownloader](http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/android/imagedownloader/ImageDownloader.java?r=3) they are implementing cache as hard and soft cache.. and for hard cache..here

```
  // Hard cache, with a fixed maximum capacity and a life duration
private final HashMap<String, Bitmap> sHardBitmapCache =
    new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY / 2, 0.75f, true) {
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(LinkedHashMap.Entry<String, Bitmap> eldest) {
        if (size() > HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY) {
            // Entries push-out of hard reference cache are transferred to soft reference cache
            sSoftBitmapCache.put(eldest.getKey(), new SoftReference<Bitmap>(eldest.getValue()));
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
};
```

they are setting a maximum capacity value for hard cache.. now what will happen if i choose some large value as the maximum capacity..?I mean.. will it effect the other applications running as my application is taking large memory..**Other apps will be running in a completely separate instance of dalvik. They would not cause any sort of  memory pressure in the application running in this..** this is what i came to know.. if this is right.. then i can declare my hard cache of any size?I dont know much about this cache.. Correct me  if I am wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device has a fixed amount of memory, shared among all applications. To give the foreground process the memory it needs, Android will kill cached background processes. Applications that have a high memory footprint will be slower to multitask with, because the other apps will need to be created from scratch.

Symmetrically, applications that have a high memory footprint will also be killed earlier than apps that don't use as much memory. After all, killing those apps will free more memory.

**You should choose the smallest cache size that yields good performance.** Anything larger and you're wasting memory and slowing down the device.

Comment: Thnq.. [can you take a look at this question please..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135261/possible-bug-in-android-imagedownloader-class-shardbitmapcache-not-static-when)